# Trouble predicting y using Multiple Linear Regression in R

Tags: r, linear-regression, prediction

I'm trying to predict Wide Receiver yards using the lm function in R. I have several (x) variables and am attempting to predict 'Yrds2015', or y. My data frame contains 200 observations and several x variables, only 8 of which I'm attempting to fit to the model. I am using a train set, including all the actual y values and a train set without.

When I run the following script I get the desired desired result:

```
>model4 <- lm(formula = train$Yrds2015 ~ TeamThrowAttempts2015*Targets2015*AvGainPerTarget2015*Yrds2014*CBSSportsProjection2015, test)
```

e.g. I get the following predicted outputs for the first few Receivers

```
> predict(model4)
1857.51957 1723.83751 1609.94607 1410.12675 1399.85167 1429.80400 1408.10068 1189.68197 1105.72274
```

However, when I add two more x variables, both integers, the following script returns the actual y values from the train data set rather than the expected predicted value.

```
>model7 <- lm(formula = train$Yrds2015 ~ TeamThrowAttempts2015*Targets2015*AvGainPerTarget2015*Yrds2014*ESPNProjectedYrds2015*ffTodayProjection2015*CBSSportsProjection2015, test)
```

e.g.

```
> predict(model7)
1871 1834 1521 1502 1450 1400 1304 1297 1215 1214 1206
```

Can anybody please explain this issue? I'd be supremely grateful. All subsequent models have the same problem although I initially thought that was due to the fact I'd added x variables as factors.

Thanks

Comment: The first thing that strikes me is that your y variable is being gathered from one dataset while your 'data' argument, `test`, appears to be a different data set. I suspect the proper "moral" to invoke is "Never use `$` inside formulas".

Comment: You have added interactions between all terms, so perhaps perfect predicition

Comment: I didn't seem logical to me but I'm really just muddling though. I was initially calling the data from the train set but it was just returning the actual y value so i was playing around with it. Although It doesn't explain why prediction seems to work for model4 and not model7.

Comment: You are likely estimating too many parameters to the model than you have data for - getting a perfect fit. Have you looked at `summary(model7)`

Comment: eg `m <- lm(mpg ~ wt*disp*am*vs*gear*carb*qsec, mtcars) ;
all.equal(mtcars$mpg , predict(m), check.names=F)`

Comment: I don't really understand the output although I can see it is a problem:

Comment: Well, have a look at the summary of your model7: do you get a message indicating that X amount of coefficients cant be estimated, do you have missing standard errors and statistics in the summary, what is the r-squared - if so, your model is too complicated. Try adding variables (`+`) rather than applying all those interactions (`*`).